# Elegant mapping of GroupBy into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, missing-data

In order to best decide how to handle missing data of each feature in a weather dataset, I want to get the length of the longest block of NaNs for each feature and each weather station, the latter being denoted by 'id'. Although the following accomplishes this, I am aware of the code's awkwardness. What would be an elegant way to accomplish this (perhaps exploiting the GroupBy object's power)?

**Awkward code under question:**

```
max_nans = []
id_groups = weather_df.groupby('id')
for feature in weather_df.drop('id', axis=1):
    max_nans.append([max_repeated_nans(df_group[feature]) for name, df_group in id_groups])

pd.DataFrame(data=np.transpose(max_nans), index=id_groups.groups.keys(), columns=id_groups.obj.columns[1:])
```

**The function:**

```
def max_repeated_nans(a):
    mask = np.concatenate(([False],a.isnull(),[False]))
    if ~mask.any():
        return 0
    else:
        idx = np.nonzero(mask[1:] != mask[:-1])[0]
        return (idx[1::2] - idx[::2]).max()
```

**An example df:**

```
weather_df = pd.DataFrame(
{ 
'id': [1,1,1,1, 
       2,2,2,2], 
'timestamp': ['2019-01-01 00:00:00', '2019-01-01 06:00:00', '2019-01-01 12:00:00', '2019-01-01 18:00:00',
              '2019-01-01 00:00:00', '2019-01-01 06:00:00', '2019-01-01 12:00:00', '2019-01-01 18:00:00'],
'temperature': [1.0, 1.1, 1.1, 1.4,
                20.0, np.nan, 24.0, 16.0], 
'wind_speed': [2,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,
               5,5,3,2],
})
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Can you share some sample data? Ideally using the `pd.DataFrame` constructor so  someone could execute your code and see the result before looking for cleaner solutions. E.g. `weather_df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2,3], 'other_col': ['a', 'b', 'c']})`

Comment: is `max_repeated_nans` a function? You seem to be calling it like a function. You should include the function definition. You should include all necessary so that the code can be executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about applying your function to the groupby using `agg`:

```
result = weather_df.groupby('id').agg({
    'temperature': max_repeated_nans,
    'wind_speed': max_repeated_nans
})
```